# In this situation, would "saber de" or "conocer" be the better option?

Tags: verbos

I'm trying to say "it's obvious that he is familiar with their culture..." I know conocer is to be familiar with, but would that work in this situation? I've also heard that "saber de" is another option.

Answer (score 3):

As Diego explains, between those two options *conocer* works better. But if you want a more precise translation and you don't mind being a little more verbose you can use *estar familiarizado*:

> Es obvio que él **está familiarizado** con su cultura.

Answer (score 1):

`Conocer` works best for you example:

> Es obvio que él **conoce** su cultura.

You could use `saber` too, but is a little bit tricky here. You can say that somebody "sabe de matemáticas" or "sabe de XXX" to convey that they have a pretty good knowledge about the topic, but if you said

> Él sabe de su cultura

You would be saying "He is aware of their culture". To make it work with `saber` you need first to use an adverb (e.g. *bastante* or *mucho*), to change the meaning of the verb by *quantifying* his degree of knowledge, so it stops implying that he knows something but that he knows a lot about it.

> Él sabe **mucho** de su cultura

Also, you could use the locution ["acerca de"](http://lema.rae.es/drae2001/srv/search?id=1EEPAAwoODXX257zIGxj) which is used to point to what is being discussed or explained. Even then might not be enough and you m

> Él sabe *bastante* **acerca de** su cultura.